# Prevent ios pinned app refresh

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

How do I stop a pinned web page from refreshing each time the user clicks its' icon.

I have created a jqm web app with the idea that users pin it to their home page. However each time I press the corresponding icon it reloads the page. I'd like it to remain in the last viewed state until an explicit refresh is called. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not alot to go on here...

Have you tried to bind .preventDefault() to the pinned items.

```
$(youritems).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    });
```

Comment: I agree that the question is not very thorough, but since I have the same problem, I can say that this is not the correct answer. The icon referred to in the question is the icon for the web-app on the users iPhone Home Screen. The problem is that clicking that icon will always load the web-app fresh. So if the user leaves the app and then returns, the old state will be lost, and the app will start over on the first page again. The sought behaviour in this case is that the app will just load where you left it, just like the browser would.

Comment: You're right, this was 2 years ago, and looking back I realize I didn't seem to have read the question properly

Comment: I'm not sure the above is possible, but would you consider using document.localStorage, and/or store an object in the cookie to save the states from a users last visit and then reload those states when the user presses the icon?

Comment: Yes, I'll probably end up doing exactly that. I guess that's more or less what a native app would have to do, so it's not really that weird. Just feels like a bulky thing to do when you're used to the browser handling it for you...